# @AttributeOverrides not working in spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have got an embeddable class. The problem is that i want to override it attributes via @AttributeOverrides, but it is not working as i am expecting

```
@Embeddable
@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Address {
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "CITY")
    private String city;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "ZIP_CODE")
    private String zipCode;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "STREET")
    private String street;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
    private String country;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s, %s, %s, %s", country, city, street, zipCode);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Address)) return false;
        Address address = (Address) o;
        return city.equals(address.city) && zipCode.equals(address.zipCode) && street.equals(address.street)
                && country.equals(address.country);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(city, zipCode, street, country);
    }
}
```

And i have this definition for this field in my entity class

```
@Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "CITY",
                column = @Column(name = "COMPANY_BRANCH_CITY")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "zip_code",
                column = @Column(name = "COMPANY_BRANCH_ZIP_CODE")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "STREET",
                column = @Column(name = "COMPANY_BRANCH_STREET")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "COUNTRY",
            column = @Column(name = "COMPANY_BRANCH_COUNTRY"))
    })
    private Address companyBranchAddress;
```

When hibernate generating my schema, it is wrong, attributes names are from embeddable class, they are not changed:

```
Hibernate: 
    create table company_branch (
        id bigint generated by default as identity,
        company_branch_budget varchar(63) not null,
        city varchar(255),
        company_branch_phone_number varchar(255) not null,
        country varchar(255),
        street varchar(255),
        zip_code varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your original question, but a couple of comments:
1 . it's not a very good practice to have hibernate generate your schema- that's ok for small poc type projects, but you would want to have your schema managed separately.
2. why does it matter that the column names be prefixed with the table name?

Comment: @Eric 1. Thank you for advice. I think so too, but my project, as you said, is small. Just to practice. 2. Actually same reasons, just practising. Thank you for you advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the `name` of the `@AttributeOverride` should refer to the name of the field of the `@Embeddable` class but not the database column name. Also, it is case-sensitive.

So change to the following should fix the problem :

```java
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "city",column = @Column(name = "COMPANY_BRANCH_CITY")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "zipCode",column = @Column(name = "COMPANY_BRANCH_ZIP_CODE")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "street",column = @Column(name = "COMPANY_BRANCH_STREET")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "country",column = @Column(name = "COMPANY_BRANCH_COUNTRY"))
})
private Address companyBranchAddress;
```